# Get a single key value from map[string]string

Tags: dictionary, go

I have a map being stored in my cookie as followed:

```
cookieData:=   map[expiration:1533455712 ip:[ hash:dd363d13234566727743277e96 email:user@user.com]

fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(cookie)) >> map[string]string
```

Can someone please help me understand how i can get only the email value from this map?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type casting in golang is done by appending `.(T)`

```
ip := cookieData["ip"].(map[string]string)
email := ip["email"]
```

Comment: Thanks alot, Atleast i see one person interested in giving a solution, that's what i tried but i got to extra email only under this function:

[link](https://github.com/rageix/ginAuth/blob/master/example/controllers/login.go#L49)

Still trying to explore.
Cheers

Comment: cast your interface to `map[string]interface` and look it up with %v to see whats its type